# Highlight largest value in each column of `Table // TableForm`

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, style, maximum, output-formatting

I am exploring colossally abundant numbers; in particular the set of specific 'critical epsilon values'. I table the function `DivisorSigma[1, n]/n^(1 + \[Epsilon])` against `n` and the first few critical values of `\[Epsilon]` thus:

```
colossalTable1 = TableForm[
  Table[N[DivisorSigma[1, n]/n^(1 + \[Epsilon])], 
   {n, 1, 60}, {\[Epsilon], {Log[3/2]/Log[2], 
    Log[4/3]/Log[3], Log[7/6]/Log[2], 
    Log[6/5]/Log[5], Log[15/14]/Log[2], 
    Log[13/12]/Log[3], Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}]]
    //TableForm
```

What I would like is for the maximum value(s) in each column to be automatically  styled `Bold`. (It needs to be an automatic process, because I may choose to expand the extent of the rows and columns.)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the table without `TableForm` like so.

```
colossalTable1 = Table[N[DivisorSigma[1, n]/n^(1 + \[Epsilon])], {n, 1, 10},
{\[Epsilon],{Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],Log[7/6]/Log[2],Log[6/5]/Log[5],
 Log[15/14]/Log[2],Log[13/12]/Log[3], Log[31/30]/Log[2]}
}];
```

Then find the column maximums and show them.

```
bold = If[MemberQ[Max /@ Transpose[colossalTable1], #1],Text[Style[#1, Bold]], #1] &;
TableForm[Map[bold, colossalTable1, {2}]]
```

[image]

If you don't want to repeat previous column maximums use this.

```
max = Max /@ Transpose[colossalTable1];
maxpos = Flatten[Table[Append[#, i] & /@ 
Position[colossalTable1[[All, i]], max[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@max}],1];
TableForm[MapAt[Text[Style[#, Bold]] &, colossalTable1, maxpos]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using color to make the highlighting more obvious:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

highlight[m_?MatrixQ] := Module[
  {tr = Transpose@m, max, htr},
  htr = (max = Max@#;
      ReplacePart[#,
       Thread[
        Position[#, max] :>
         Style[max, Red, Bold]]]) & /@ tr;
  Transpose@htr]

(colossalTable1 = Table[
    N[DivisorSigma[1, n]/n^(1 + ϵ)],
    {n, 1, 60},
    {ϵ, {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],
      Log[7/6]/Log[2], Log[6/5]/Log[5],
      Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3],
      Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}]);

colossalTable1 // highlight // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the spec a little differently than @PlatoManiac

```
colossalTable1 = Table[N[DivisorSigma[1, n]/n^(1 + \[Epsilon])],
    {n, 1, 60},
    {\[Epsilon], {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],
      Log[7/6]/Log[2], Log[6/5]/Log[5],
      Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3],
      Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}
    ];"";
boldMax[l0_] := Block[
  {m},
  m = Max[l0];
  (Text /@ l0) /. {Text[m] -> Text[Style[m, Bold]]}
  ]
Transpose[boldMax /@ Transpose[colossalTable1]] // TableForm
```

[image]